# Using an older version of Node and NPM on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, node.js, npm

I need to install an older version of NODE and NPM on freebsd to work with GHOST, a pretty cool blogging platform.  I want to do this on my own system, preferably on a FreeBSD VM.

The system is setup, but when it comes to NODE, I specifically did:

```
pkg install node4-4.2.3
```

Which installs fine, but when I do:

```
pkg install npm (whatever version I can find using pkg search npm)
```

It tries to upgrade node to version 5.x.x

Any help with this would be appreciated.  In this case, I would really like to avoid using a one-click app deploy, or using shared hosting, etc.  Part of it is also for me to learn a bit more about node/npm on freebsd, and also be able to install multiple node sites on the same machine.

Comment: For GHOST you need node4 and npm?

Answer (score 1):

To install `www/npm` with `www/node4` you have to use the ports system.

The port `www/npm` has the default build option

```
NODE4=off: Use www/node4 as backend
```

You can turn that on with

```
cd /usr/port/www/npm; make config
```

and build the port with your favourite build tool or

```
 cd /usr/port/www/npm; make install clean
```

You might want to encapsulate your GHOST setup in a jail so the `www/npm` package that is using `www/node4` is not interfering with the normal `www/npm` package you might use.